# How to install custom version of Laravel Modules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-modules

I want to install [this](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) package called Laravel Modules and because my Laravel version is v8, I need to install the version 8 of Laravel Modules as well.

By default the command line for doing that is this:

```
composer require nwidart/laravel-module
```

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You just have a spelling mistake, it is as simple as that,

**Run the following:**

```
composer require nwidart/laravel-modules 8
```

it is nwidart/laravel-**modules** not **module**